# JavaScript vs php amazon api

Tags: javascript, php

So the amazon product advertising api is in php but I don't want to slow down my servers so is there a way to use the amazon api client side instead of sever side? Or does the php script not even effect the severs performance on a large scale? Thank you to any answers.

Answer (score 2):

We update 600,000 listings in one feed and 400,000 in another.The speed of each is a little under 30 seconds.

The key for this to be plausible is to figure out the flat file feeds(while they way be harder)first because the speed of the call is based more on number of queries rather than file size.

This is because amazon runs a query system. Which means they accept a feed, tell you they received it, and an undisclosed time later they process is.

To fully answer your question, the only way to really know if something fits your system is to build it and see.